# how to map properties type to database column

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I have a definition in my domain object as `Properties deviceMapping`, and the corresponding mapped database column in my database(mysql) is blob.

Is that fine? because I am getting the following error and I think there should be a problem in mapping with the DB columns.

> Error 500: Executing action [save] of controller
>   [se.accumulate.wizard.SubmissionController] caused exception: could
>   not deserialize; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: i would think that properties is some kind of map and schould be serialized as one-to-many no?

Comment: Thanks for the response Firo...yeah its kind of map and it can handle all kinds of relations(1-to-1, 1-to-many and many-to-many), as I have handled all these using the same Properties type. I think the mapping is fine, the same error has not been thrown from other computer, weird though...

Comment: it seems that in the case of binary-column the whole map is binary-serialized and to do that, all objects in the map must also be serializable. Can you check that all objects you put into it are serializable?

Comment: Hi Firo, how do I need to check whether all the objects in the map are serializable?

Comment: try to serialize each value you put in the map alone. i don't know groovy, but in java it is `ObjectOutputStream`'s  `.writeObject(prs);`

Comment: By converting the properties to string, this error has been avoided...thanks for the responses Firo...